# ¿Cómo consigo una lista de elementos a partir de una lista de diccionarios?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-7

Tengo un array consistente en diferentes objectos. Una lista de diccionarios, vaya:

```
[
    {'a': 1, 'b':2},
    {'a': 5, 'b':6}
]
```

Y me gustaría conseguir un array que contenga el valor de un índice concreto de todos los objetos. En este caso, el índice "a", para tener una salida del tipo:

```
[1, 5]
```

Sé que puedo gestionarlo con un bucle

```js
var datos = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':5, 'b':6}]
resultado = [];
for (let dato of datos) {
resultado.push(dato.a);
}
console.log(resultado);
```

Sin embargo, me gustaría poder hacer algo un poco más elegante usando `.reduce()` y no estoy siendo capaz más que de iterar y decir algo así como:

```js
var datos = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':5, 'b':6}]

let res = datos.reduce((v, item) => {return item.a});
console.log(res);
```

Que me devuelve el elemento "a" pero solo del último registro.

Comment: (no es que escribiera la pregunta sabiendo la respuesta, sino que luego seguí investigando y la encontré. Si encontráis mejores maneras, por favor añadidlas en forma de respuesta o editando la mía)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, veo que no era tan complicado, simplemente debía usar `map()`:

```js
var datos = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':5, 'b':6}]

let res = datos.map((item) => {return item.a});
console.log(res);
```

Y para usar `reduce` la sintaxis es algo más compleja:

```
datos.reduce((resultado, item) => [...resultado, item.a], []);
```

Implica ir añadiendo con el operador `...`.

```js
var datos = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':5, 'b':6}]

let res = datos.reduce((resultado, item) => [...resultado, item.a], []);
console.log(res);
```

He sacado la información de diversas respuestas de [Using the reduce function to return an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35431292/1983854), así como de mis adaptaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo otra alternativa con `reduce`:

```js
let lista=[{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':5, 'b':6}];
let res=lista.reduce( (res,{a,b}) => res.concat( a ), []);
console.log(res)
```

Y tambien puedes obviar el `return` en la funcion `map`

```js
var datos = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':5, 'b':6}]
let res = datos.map(({a}) => a);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! La sintaxis es muy densa, ¿te importaría explicarla un poco?